# Executing a command that is the argument of a program

Tags: bash

I want to run a program that takes 1 argument and I want that argument to be the output of a command.

Something like:

```
./program $ python -c 'print(stuff)'
```

I want the argument of the program to be the output of the command `python -c 'print(stuff)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were just <strike>two</strike> four characters short:

```
./program "$(python -c 'print(stuff)')"
```

... though it seems python wants stuff to be in quotes:

```
./program "$(python -c 'print("stuff")')"
```

Comment: The one caveat here is that command substitution `$( ...)` strips any trailing newlines from the output before it hands it to `program` -- just in case that's important to your program.